# Passing data between EditTexts using TextWatcher

Tags: android, textwatcher

I'm writing an Android app with multiple EditText fields that will compute the sum, difference, and product of each other on the fly.

For instance, there is an order total, amount received, and tip EditText. The tip will be computed as `tip = amountReceived - orderTotal`.

I also have a gas reimbursement EditText. I've created an instance of `sharedPreferences` to choose between getting paid by the mile, or by the delivery that is taken by the driver.

However, although all of my calculations are working correctly, I'm trying to display the final total value in my `EditText` field named `GrandTotal`.

My code is as follows:

```
if (ratePerMile.equals("") && !ratePerDelivery.equals(""))
    {
        eMileage.setText(ratePerDelivery);
    }

    else
    {
        eMilesDriven.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after){}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count){}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                if (getCurrentFocus() == eMilesDriven)
                {
                    sAmountReceived = eAmountReceived.getText().toString();
                    sTotalCost = eTotalCost.getText().toString();
                    sMileage = eMileage.getText().toString();
                    sTip = eTip.getText().toString();

                    try
                    {
                        milesDriven = eMilesDriven.getText().toString();
                        dMilesDriven = Double.parseDouble(milesDriven);
                        dRatePerMile = Double.parseDouble(ratePerMile);
                        dMultiply = dRatePerMile * dMilesDriven;
                        dGrandTotal = dTip + dMultiply;
                    } catch(NumberFormatException e){}

                    sMileage = String.valueOf(dMultiply);

                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
                    sMileage = df.format(dMultiply);

                    eMileage.setText(sMileage);

                    sGrandTotal = String.valueOf(dGrandTotal);
                    sGrandTotal = df.format(dGrandTotal);
                    eGrandTotal.setText(sGrandTotal);
                }
            }
        });
```

Everything works fine when I input the data in a certain way.

The app will compute the tip, and then add that total to a delivery charge (or gas reimbursement), resulting in a grandTotal. This is all the result of inputting the order total first, and then the amount received, which will display the rest of the fields correctly.

However, when the order total and tip are input first, the amount received will update accordingly, and the delivery charge (gas reimbursement) will display as the delivery charge and the GrandTotal, not adding the delivery charge to the tip. Thank you in advance to anyone who can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: eTotalCost, eAmountReceived, eTip, eMileage, and eGrandTotal are all references to my EditText fields. I named the variables the same, but with an "s" instead of "e" for when I converted them to strings. And any variable with a "d" in front is a double form of the variable to do calculations. dRatePerMile is my variable that I passed with Shared Preferences, so that the user can choose amount per mile that they get paid from a settings menu. dMultiply is a variable that I'm using to store the result of the calculation, which is an EditText for amount of miles the user drove, multiplied by the amount they are reimbursed that they chose in the settings menu.

Here is my full code: (Sorry if it's too long)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.order_details);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactlist);

    db = new PhoneBookHandler(this);

    contactList = db.getAllContacts();

    adapter = new PhonebookAdapter(this, contactList);

    eAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);

    eTotalCost = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.orderTotal);
    eAmountReceived = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountReceived);
    eTip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tip);
    eMileage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mileage);
    eGrandTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grandTotal);
    eMilesDriven = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.milesDriven);

    // use shared preferences to inflate mileage edittext with data entered in settings menu
    ratePerDelivery = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("ratePerDeliveryPref", null);
    ratePerMile = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("ratePerMilePref", null);

    eAmountReceived.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after){}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count){}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            if (getCurrentFocus() == eAmountReceived)
            {
                sAmountReceived = eAmountReceived.getText().toString();
                sTotalCost = eTotalCost.getText().toString();
                sMileage = eMileage.getText().toString();
                sTip = eTip.getText().toString();

                try
                {
                    dAmountReceived = Double.parseDouble(sAmountReceived);
                    dTotalCost = Double.parseDouble(sTotalCost);

                    dSubtract = dAmountReceived - dTotalCost;
                    dMileage = Double.parseDouble(sMileage);
                    dGrandTotal = dSubtract + dMileage;
                } catch(NumberFormatException e){}

                sTip = String.valueOf(dSubtract);

                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
                sTip = df.format(dSubtract);

                eTip.setText(sTip);

                sGrandTotal = String.valueOf(dGrandTotal);
                sGrandTotal = df.format(dGrandTotal);
                eGrandTotal.setText(sGrandTotal);
            }
        }
    });


    eTip.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after){}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count){}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (getCurrentFocus() == eTip)
            {
                sAmountReceived = eAmountReceived.getText().toString();
                sTotalCost = eTotalCost.getText().toString();
                sMileage = eMileage.getText().toString();
                sTip = eTip.getText().toString();

                try {
                    dTip = Double.parseDouble(sTip);
                    dTotalCost = Double.parseDouble(sTotalCost);

                    dAdd = dTotalCost + dTip;
                    dMileage = Double.parseDouble(sMileage);
                    dGrandTotal = dTip + dMileage;
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                }

                sAmountReceived = String.valueOf(dAdd);

                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
                sAmountReceived = df.format(dAdd);

                eAmountReceived.setText(sAmountReceived);

                sGrandTotal = String.valueOf(dGrandTotal);
                sGrandTotal = df.format(dGrandTotal);
                eGrandTotal.setText(sGrandTotal);
            }
        }
    });


    if (ratePerMile.equals("") && !ratePerDelivery.equals(""))
    {
        eMileage.setText(ratePerDelivery);
    }

    else
    {
        eMilesDriven.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after){}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count){}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                if (getCurrentFocus() == eMilesDriven)
                {
                    sAmountReceived = eAmountReceived.getText().toString();
                    sTotalCost = eTotalCost.getText().toString();
                    sMileage = eMileage.getText().toString();
                    sTip = eTip.getText().toString();

                    try
                    {
                        milesDriven = eMilesDriven.getText().toString();
                        dMilesDriven = Double.parseDouble(milesDriven);
                        dRatePerMile = Double.parseDouble(ratePerMile);
                        dMultiply = dRatePerMile * dMilesDriven;
                        dGrandTotal = dTip + dMultiply;
                    } catch(NumberFormatException e){}

                    sMileage = String.valueOf(dMultiply);

                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
                    sMileage = df.format(dMultiply);

                    eMileage.setText(sMileage);

                    sGrandTotal = String.valueOf(dGrandTotal);
                    sGrandTotal = df.format(dGrandTotal);
                    eGrandTotal.setText(sGrandTotal);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please write a map about which EditText is mapped to which value? Like:  eMileage = tip, sGrandTotal = grandtotal etc. it's not clear to me which edittext contains which field.

Comment: No problem. Sorry about that. I edited my question and provided my whole code to clarify what is going on. It's kind of hard to describe. Basically in one method, I'm getting the value of the tip stored in a variable called dSubtract. And in another method, saving the tip as "dTip". That might be what is messing me up. If I already have the value for mileage inputted before I populate the rest of the fields with data, it works perfect. But if I input the mileage last, it doesn't add the mileage to the tip to display grandTotal. It just displays the value for mileage in grandTotal.